# How work with Cron Expression and parse Specific table in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, cron, cronexpression

I need to create a Php File, which include Cron Expression. Hint: https://github.com/mtdowling/cron-expression

The schedule of when to run needs to be read from the “CRON” entry field in mySQL.

I want the code to parse the cron entry to find the next scheduled run, and then use that data to group results and display the Results on PHP page.

the First Schedule run the 2nd wednesday of the month, and them 3rd wed, and 4th wed. and also schedules running every quarter.

i tried to implement this to the PHP file, but how i can get the

the database Table "test" got a field called "cron entry" and every entry in the database got in the Cron Entry field diferent Cron Schedules, example 8 entries got "0 22 * * 3#2" 5 entries got "0 22 * * 3#3"  3 entries got "0 22 3,6,9,12 3#2" 2 entries got "0 22 * * 3#4" 10 entries got "0 22 3,6,9,12 3#3" and one entry got "0 22 3,6,9,12 3#4".

How make the Cron Expression to query the database parse the entries running the next schedule and include the results.

```
<?php

require_once '/vendor/autoload.php';

// Works with predefined scheduling definitions
$cron = Cron\CronExpression::factory('**0 22 * * 3#2**');
$cron = Cron\CronExpression::factory('**0 22 * 3,6,9,12 3#2**');
$cron->isDue();
echo $cron->getNextRunDate()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
echo $cron->getPreviousRunDate()->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
?>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is a little short on information. Can you share what you have tried, and what problems have you run into?

Comment: Hello i just included more information. thanks for you help